# how to test controller with function decorators in nestjs

Tags: typescript, jestjs, controller, nestjs

I have just implemented an interceptor that is used as a decorator in the controller, but when I try to run the test for the controller, the interceptor doesn't seem to be called, so I don't know if I am doing it wrong or if it is not possible to have the decorator functions called in unit tests.

here is my test case :

```js
it('should throw an error', async () =>
    const input = makeInput(1);
    const user = makeUserWithApplications();
    const postResponse = makeResponse(
        'input', Status.USER_ERROR, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST
    )
    jest.spyOn(httpService, 'post').mockImplementation(() => {
        throw new BadRequestException(postResponse);
    });
    jest.spyOn(repository, 'findById').mockImplementation(
        () => Promise.resolve(input)
    );
    jest.spyOn(application, 'checkUserPermission').mockImplementation();
    // jest.mock('../../../shared/exceptions/invalidSolverDataException.ts', () => ())
    jest.spyOn(service, 'getData').mockImplementation(() => {
         throw new BadRequestException(postResponse);
    });
        
    const exception = await getExceptionAsync(() =>  
        inputController.getData(1, user ))
          
    expect(exception).toBeInstanceOf(InvalidSolverDataException); 
    
});
```

and this the controller:

```
@UseInterceptors(SolverInterceptor)
@Get(':inputId/visuWithApi')
async getData(@Param('inputId') inputId: number, @GetUser() user: User): Promise<model> {
    const input = await this.inputService.findById(
        inputId, user.company.id, u => u.instance, u => u.instance.application
    );
    const application: Application = input.instance.application;
    await this.applicationService.checkUserPermission(user, application);

    return this.inputService.getData(input);
}
```